# Turn Kinect in the left and the right

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, openni2-camera, primesense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi;
I used the openni function xnUSBSendControl to move the KInect's motor up and down, and now I'm looking to turn that motor in the left and right.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190573/turn-kinect-in-the-left-and-the-right/) by [faty](https://answers.ros.org/users/20001/faty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-19**:
You may be interested in the [kinect_aux](http://wiki.ros.org/kinect_aux) package for tilting the Kinect using a ROS interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no motor inside the kinect to control the left/right direction. There is only one motor, and it is for controlling the up/down direction. If you look at Step 5 of [ifixit's Kinect Teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Microsoft+Kinect+Teardown/4066), you can see the single motor.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1